# Python-Tornado: Can I serve static file as "/" without "masking" other routes?

Tags: python, tornado

Can I configure a route in Tornado to serve a static "index.html" file as "/"?  This *almost* works, but then routes **everything** to the StaticFileHandler.

If I leave out the wildcard '(.*)', then I get:

```
"TypeError: StaticFileHandler.get() missing 1 required positional argument: 'path'"
```

Directory tree:

```
├── static
│   ├── index.html
│   └── test.js
└── test_app.py
```

test_app.py:

```
import asyncio
import tornado.web
import os

PORT=8020

static_path=os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'static')

class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.write("Hello, world")

def make_app():
    return tornado.web.Application([
        (r"/(.*)", tornado.web.StaticFileHandler,
            {'path':static_path, 'default_filename':'index.html'}),
        (r"/main", MainHandler),
    ])

async def main():
    app = make_app()
    app.listen(PORT)
    print (f"listening on {PORT}")
    await asyncio.Event().wait()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("starting asyncio main loop")
    asyncio.run(main())
    await asyncio.Event().wait()
```

Comment: Put the `/(.*)` route *last* in the list of routes…!?

Comment: @deceze - Yep, that worked. Thanks!!  Just trying to come up to speed. Guess that makes sense the routes are searched in-order.